# Amadeus API returns Internal error with all requests (Production Key)

Tags: api, amadeus

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "38189",
            "title": "Internal error",
            "detail": "An internal error occured, please contact your administrator",
            "status": "500"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get this error when I use production key to send requests to AMADEUS API, this error returns just with production key but not with test key. Despite I updated header to " Accept application/vnd.amadeus+json" the error still returns.

Here one of the requests:

https://api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=MAD&destination=PAR&departureDate=2019-08-01&adults=1&nonStop=false&max=6

Comment: Code 500 is likely an error on their side, something you should contact them about.

Comment: I checked the APIs, they are up and running in production.      
                                                  
When you do the authorization call to get your token, do you call:
         
https://api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token
      
with your API Key and API Secret from production?
      
I tried to find your account to check your API Key/Secret but I didn't, could you please send your information at developers:at:amadeus.com? So we can see if it's a configuration problem.
        
FYI the API call is right.

Comment: yes i did that and it generates access token which i use to send requests

Comment: ok i have sent my information to amadeus.com .

Answer (score 0):

We had a configuration issue on our side. Everything has been fixed, You should be able to use all the APIs in production.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This is happening again or was not fixed properly.

Comment: yes this is happening to me as well